# Bootstrap: How to make table shrink to screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

When I shrink my browser screen to mimic a mobile display, the table acts like I want it to: it shrinks to fit. View here:

[image]

However, when I enter Responsive Design Mode on Safari (or when I visit the site on a mobile device), the table cuts off. View here:

[image]

As you can tell in the second photo, I have a `<div class="table-responsive">` wrapped around my table. This makes the table scrollable on a mobile display. I don't want a scroll, I want it to display everything, just shrunk a bit.

My data cells' widths are set to percentages (e.g. 5%, 10%, 30%) so it's not like the table is being forced into overflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then don't use responsive-table. If you want the table to just shrink then use percentages alone.

Comment: Hi Rachel, I've tried this as well. When I don't use table-responsive, the table simply overflows rightward off the screen.

Comment: Then your text is too long. It has to cut off somewhere. Maybe reduce padding or something. Can't say until you post html and css.

Comment: @RachelS is correct, but for it to work the way you want, you also need to set table-layout: fixed;

Comment: I combined the suggestions you both gave and achieved the effect I wanted. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a media query for devices to change the CSS for only that device.
Something like...

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
// insert CSS here to make adjustments for this view

}
```